# How getting the next line in a dataframe following a slicing based on value conditions?

Tags: python, dataframe

As an example, I have 2 following dataframes.

```
In [29]: pbm_sig
Out[29]: 
                              Open  Trouble
Timestamp                                  
2019-12-22 06:40:00+00:00  7137.00  dis_val
2019-12-22 06:45:00+00:00  7134.34  dis_val
2019-12-22 06:50:00+00:00  7135.03  dis_val
2019-12-22 06:55:00+00:00  7131.74  dis_val

In [30]: known_ca
Out[30]: 
                              Open    Trouble Corrective
Timestamp                                               
2019-12-22 06:40:00+00:00  7137.00    dis_val     remove
2019-12-22 06:45:00+00:00  7134.34    dis_val     remove
2019-12-22 06:50:00+00:00  7135.03    dis_val       keep
2019-12-22 06:55:00+00:00  7131.74    dis_val     remove
2019-12-22 07:00:00+00:00  7188.00    dis_val        add
2019-12-22 07:05:00+00:00  7389.00  short_dur     remove
```

known_ca is a much bigger dataframe, but here is an extract that contains the relevant data.
I use following code to retrieve rows of interest (with respect to what contains pbm_sig).

```
# Check if problem is found in corrective action database based on timestamps and problem type.
corrective_actions = known_ca[(known_ca['Trouble'].isin(pbm_sig['Trouble'])) & (known_ca.index.isin(pbm_sig.index))]
```

And now the question. I would like to get the immediate next line in known_ca, the one that follows the last line retrieved in corrective_actions dataframe. So, with given example, I am referring to this line:

```
2019-12-22 07:00:00+00:00  7188.00    dis_val        add
```

Please, do you have any how to do this?
I thank you for your help.
Have a good day.
Bests,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift the mask:

```
mask_orig = (known_ca['Trouble'].isin(pbm_sig['Trouble'])) & (known_ca.index.isin(pbm_sig.index))
mask_shifted = mask_orig.shift(1)
```

If you don't want the original values to intervene, exclude them, i.e.

```
mask_shifted = mask_shifted & ~mask_orig
df = df[mask_shifted]
```

Comment: Hello Oleg O, thanks a lot for your feedback. Actually, I will want to add this last line to mask_orig on the conditions that value in 'Corrective' column is 'add', and that value in 'Trouble' column is the same as the 1st row in pbm_sig dataframe (so, here, 'dis_val'). Do you know if there is an 'extend' function instead of the 'shift' you are proposing so as to keep the first row as well? If not, I guess I will use your proposal to get only the last row, and then use append() to add it to mask_orig. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: In this case you can do logical OR to the original mask, i.e. `mask_orig | mask_shifted`, if I understood you correctly.